# Psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "{random thing}" does not exist -- using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm very new to the whole programming thing but and ive ran into a pretty annoying problem.

This is a small slice of some code I had to do for school and I've ran into a problem where it keeps telling me the variables I'm trying to put into the `{}` brackets are not columns, when they shouldn't even be seen as columns in the first place. They are variables linked to some buttons and input things via Tkinter, I just want them to be placed into the columns.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO reviews(name,messae,date,time,location,messaeg_id) VALUES ({},{},{},{},{},{})".format(naam, review, datumm, tijdd, locatie, review_id))
```

I've tried quite a few things like putting '' and ""s basically everywhere you could think of (I think), tried it with only one column and value, which just gave me a different error:

> (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "VALUE")

If I kept it as VALUES instead of VALUE it gave me the same error as the main one this question is about.

Also "tried" some solutions I found on this site but since I'm still very new, I found it hard to adapt those solutions over to my code, hence why I've resorted to asking a question myself for once lol.

BTW it's pretty late here at the time of writing this and English is not my first language so please excuse any grammatical errors and what not lol

Comment: Your mistake is using `format`, if for no other reason then it is a big SQL injection problem in the making. See [Query parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for how to do this correctly.